# Can haar cascade detect sinle eye in livestream

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier, eye-tracking

I want to track eye from an head mount camera and i am using haar cascade @ eyecascade

i am able to detect eye when two eyes are in the frame and unable to track when only single eye is in the frame of the camera.

Does eyecascade in haar cascade recognize when only one eye is in the frame of the camera

Comment: can you use a single fixed input image where both eyes are detected successfully? If you remove one eye by cropping the image, will the 2nd eye still be detected?

Comment: @Micka yes i can detect both eyes from live stream and as soon as one eye is out of the frame its not detecting the other eye 
can u share any code regarding that if it can detect single eye

Comment: Depends on what haar cascade you are using for eye detection. If you use **haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml** or **haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml** that are available in the opencv installation, you can detect single eye also.

Comment: @I.Newton i am using haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml  and will work on those two haar cascade algorithms 
if u have any code can u share

Comment: I used them earlier in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766764/how-can-i-invert-the-cursor-movement-in-python/45999505#45999505) check that for reference. You just need to add those xml files in current working directory.

Comment: @I.Newton do u have any similar code for c++
  I am using c++ for my project

Comment: No, i dont have